# I need make the wordpress plugin "NS Cloner" appear for all users, not just for the network administrator

Tags: wordpress

Please, any wordpress expert?

I need a help in plugin, I have a plugin "NS Cloner" that only appears in wordpress admin in multisite network mode, I need it to appear in the admin of all users !, and not only in the network owner ...

Comment: This is not the right community to ask this question. You should probably try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original author of the NS Cloner and would be happy to provide a more detailed answer if you post to wordpress.stackexchange.com as suggested.

In a nutshell the NS Cloner operates at the WP Multisite Network level and therefore requires Super Admin rights in order to run the privileged operations required to clone / copy full sites. That's the reason that it only appears in the Network Admin area. You could pretty easily add a custom menu for it to appear in individual site dashboard menus BUT some operations might still fail anyway unless you make every site admin a Super Admin as well which gives them full control over the entire network and probably not something you want to do.

Future versions of NS Cloner might have local site cloning capabilities in addition to the multisite cloning capabilities.